# How to know if bad block is logical or physical?

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, bad-sectors, bad-blocks

I cannot read some files from external disk (NTFS system). Windows cannot read from this disk now.

I am just scanning the disk using badblocks (Linux). The program prints a lot of bad blocks.

I have read that there can be logical and physical errors on the disk(?)
Do these bad blocks are physical or logical? How can I know it?

Is it possible to repair physical bad block or only mark it as unusable?

Comment: "Is it possible to repair physical bad block" - No

Answer (score 0):

Badblocks are generally blocks that can not be written or read anymore. You won't be able to physically recover the data without making changes or getting lucky. You can't repair it if it's a permanent damage. Certain companies do offer services that might be able to recover the data but don't expect the hard drive to survive the process as it is. They might open it, change parts or do any other number of things to read that data and it's usually a pretty expensive process.

P. S. Don't try to open the disk yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A bad block on a drive means you can no longer read or write to that sector of the drive, the causes are physical. If you see bad blocks on your drive, I suggest it time to move your data off as this can affect parts of other files.

As you mentioned you can view these bad blocks by using `badblocks` on Linux.

`sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda6 > bad_blocks.txt`

Bad blocks are damaged, this damage is permanent and cannot be fixed.